# camelot-test-maven-plugin: config not found! Paths=[]

Tags: plugins, apache-camel, message-queue

I'm trying to execute **camelot-test:run** goal on [Camelot](https://github.com/camelot-framework/camelot)-based multimodule project where one of the modules is using **camelot-test-maven-plugin**:

```
$ mvn clean compile camelot-test:run
.... (a lot of output)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Cannot initialize plugins system: config not found! Paths=[]
    at ru.yandex.qatools.camelot.core.impl.GenericPluginsEngine.loadConfigs(GenericPluginsEngine.java:391)[camelot-core-2.1.12.jar:]
    at ru.yandex.qatools.camelot.core.impl.GenericPluginsEngine.getConfigs(GenericPluginsEngine.java:149)[camelot-core-2.1.12.jar:]
    at ru.yandex.qatools.camelot.core.impl.GenericPluginsEngine.getPluginsMap(GenericPluginsEngine.java:231)[camelot-core-2.1.12.jar:]
    at ru.yandex.qatools.camelot.core.impl.ProcessingEngineImpl$1.onCamelContextStarted(ProcessingEngineImpl.java:86)[camelot-core-2.1.12.jar:]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1987)[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1851)[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1683)[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1651)[camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
    ...and so on and so forth
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should launch camelot-test-maven-plugin directly from the submodule directory, containing camelot.xml. The fact is that you cannot use it from the root module directory. This behaviour is typical for the similar maven plugins (like jetty-maven-plugin).